# PHP : Saving base64 encoded PDF file

Tags: php, base64

I am trying to save a pdf file from a response. Here is the
 [API documentatin](http://docs.shipstation.apiary.io/#reference/orders/create-label-for-order)

`Creates a shipping label for a given order. The labelData field returned in the response is a base64 encoded PDF value. Simply decode and save the output as a PDF file to retrieve a printable label`.

Here is my code for saving the pdf file.

```
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        $data = base64_decode($response->labelData);
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        //echo $data;
        $path = 'E:/newly_created_file'.time().'.pdf';
        file_put_contents($path,$data);
```

When I `echo $data` in the browser, it shows the response like

`%PDF-1.4 %���� 2 0 obj <>stream x�+�r �26S0�4SI�r � �*T0T0BC]#=]ccC=#��\��4C�|�@.GF� endstream endobj 4 0 obj <>>>/Contents 2 0 R/Parent`

and when I save the data, it generates an empty pdf file which fails to open.

What is wrong here?

UPDATE : Respose has correct data as show in attached image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This header needs only when you show pdf file in browser, not store in file.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

Remove it.

Comment: Removed but I am still getting the empty pdf that fails to open.

Comment: Debug everythings by steps. Is you get proper value from `curl_exec($ch)`, next `json_decode(curl_exec($ch))` next `$response->labelData` next `base64_decode($response->labelData)` . Can you show pdf file in browser  ?

Comment: yes, the results are correct as shown in attached image (i have updated the question). It also fails to open in browser

Answer (score 0):

Hard to find problem with no information about data from API.
Execute code:

```
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
echo $response->labelData;
exit;
```

and post results here, so we can try to find what is wrong.

Comment: the output->labelData is shown in the attached snapshot and as per documentation, it is the encoded pdf.